# Regular expression for string price with hyphen

Tags: c#, regex

Can I have a regular expression for identify below mentioned dynamic change text.

```
"5.6-grooming"
```

5.6 = is **price** coming as a string. The price can be any number up to two decimal places.

after the **-** can have any string value

Comment: @devnull Why the literal brackets?

Comment: @arshajii So that `.` is interpreted as a *literal*.

Comment: @devnull I was referring to `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: @arshajii that's grouping.  Try searching for backreferences in regex.

Comment: @devnull `([0-9])` is grouping as parenthesis has special meaning - `\(` is escaping it, to mean a literal `(`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP It might have different interpretations depending upon the what you're using.  For example, you'd need to say `\(...\)` in `sed` unless you're using extended re.

Comment: @sampath You should should specify the environment, what you want to capture, and how variable the digits can be, since everyone is making a different guess... From what you have stated, `5\.6\-`could be an answer...

Comment: @beroe I have updated.

Comment: @Sampath So to clarify, can "5.6" be any price like the following: `10,1200,5.50,3.33,2.01,8.5,0.00,0` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Yep,Can be.But Only 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\d+(?:\.\d+)?"` parses just an integer or double value

Comment: What is the use of @ before?

Comment: Removed.That is needed when work with c# on asp.net app.

Comment: So, while you are posting, you should have mention in it. That help others

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^\([0-9]\+\|[0-9]*\.[0-9]\+\)-.*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
\d+(\.\d\d?)?-.*
```

- \d+ : for the left side of decimal digits
- (.\d\d?)? : will match no decimal, single digit after decimal, double digits after decimal

so for price, **5**, **6.7**, **8.91** all three cases will be matched

Answer (score 0):

1. Identifies if price has been passed.

   ^[\d]*(.[\d]+)?\-.*
2. Get the price

   ^[\d]*(.[\d]+)?

Comment: You don't need [] around single entities... And * means this would match the word without any price.

Comment: @beroe: I prefer to include [] just for readability and maintenance. If you want to add new character in the class then it is easy. First star covers the price like (.254). It will match the work without price iff you provide something like '-item' which is not expected. I am assuming that if hyphen is there then there would be price before that.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d+(\.\d\d)?\-.+/
```

`\d+` - One or more numbers

`(\.\d\d)?` "." followed by two digits (optional)

`\-.+` A "-" followed by one or more characters (any character = `.`)

```
/(\d+(\.\d\d)?)\-.+/
```

Will put the whole number in matching group 1

Answer (score 0):

The simple pattern for matching a real number as well as an integer would be,

```
`/^[\d.]+/`
```

To specifically match a real number with "."

```
`/^\d[.][\d.]*/`
```

To match the price from your string

```
`/^\d[.][\d.]*-.+$/`
```

Place the capturing parenthesis around the the part of you interest.
To capture just the number
    `/^(\d[.][\d.]*)-.+$/`

good luck