# Regular expression to get any numbers not only integers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this string and need to get the number (integer or double) out of it.

**String 1 GMT +2**

**String 2 - GMT +2.5**

I have used this to get the integer out of String 1 and need to know how to write a generic one to get 2 or 2.5

below is what i have written.

```
return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
```

but it doesnt return 2.5 but takes it as 25 instead of 2.5

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005899/regular-expression-for-string-price-with-hyphen/19006035#19006035 Use this regex instead of yours

Comment: Have you tried anything that's likely to actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is always ending with numbers, you can use slightly modified code:

```
preg_replace('/^\D*/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Fails for a string like `foo 123 bar`

Comment: @Kolink: With due respect that is not the pattern of OP's input strings, which is aways ending with numbers.

Comment: That's fair enough, however just because it works for the two strings given doesn't mean it will work for every string the OP might have. Not to mention, OP might take your answer and believe it will work in all cases of "finding a number that may have a decimal part", only to find it doesn't - I've seen this sort of thing happen on SO a lot ;)

Comment: @Kolink: That's a fair point I added caveat of this regex in my answer. OP please see if this works for you otherwise if you have different input strings then I request editing the question with more detailed examples.

Comment: @anubhava do you know why this prints 2.30 - 0 = 2.3 instead of 2.30 ? what happens to the last digit of zero ?

Comment: @mazraara It is not a significant digit and therefore isn't shown. You'll need to use `number_format` or `sprintf` with suitable paramters to force insignificant digits to be shown.

Comment: @mazraara: Did this answer work for you? If please consider marking it as accepted to help future visitors of this page.